# Heisenberg boxes image for Matching Pursuit

Tags: matlab, time-frequency

I'm using the MATLAB algotirhm Matching Pursuit to obtain the Gabor atoms forming a signal.
But now I want to graph them in a "Heisenberg boxes" graph.
Does someone how if is there a function to graph them like this?:

[image]

[image]

Or maybe I should write a function for graph. In that case, I know the time and frequency which are the coordinates of the atom, also I have the scale which give me the width in time. But how can I know how much wide is in frequency? I suppose that I must have a certain area and by knowning the width in time I can calculate the width in frequency but I'm not sure.

-------------------------UPDATED----------------------------

I made my own function:

```
function plotGaborAtomos(N,params,fs)
%N is the length of the atoms
%params gives the parameters from Gabor atom
%params is size 3xnCols where first row has the scale, second row has timeShifts and third row the freqs
%params = scales timeShifts freqs
nCols = size(params,2);
a = [ 0 N/fs 0 fs/2];
plot(a(1)-.5, a(3)-.5);
axis(a);
hold on;
titlestr = 'Sonido prueba';
titlestr = ['Heisenberg boxes: ' titlestr ];
title(titlestr);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Frequency');

area = N;
for i=1:nCols
    s = params(1,i);
    tCentral = params(2,i)/fs; 
    fCentral = params(3,i)*fs;
    t0 = tCentral - (s/fs)/2; 
    t1 = tCentral + (s/fs)/2; 
    wideFreq = area/(s) * fs/2/N;
    f0 = fCentral-wideFreq;
    f1 = fCentral+wideFreq;
    plot([t0 t1 t1 t0 t0], [f0 f0 f1 f1 f0])
    plot( tCentral, fCentral, 'o')
end
```

Using it in a signal of length 256 gives me this:
[image]

As can be seen, the sampling frequency is 44100Hz

Comment: It looks like you've already done some work on the plotting. Are you still looking for a reply?

Comment: I updated to have the solution in here. But if I'm wrong in something all replies are wellcome.